# I'm trying to automaticaly start|stop|restart apache tomcat server using a python script

Tags: java, python, tomcat7

I'm trying to run, restart and stop apache tomcat 7.0.63 by using python script but when try to run this script in windows it is not executing following command

> catalina.sh jpda start

Apache server not also not started. This the script I'm using

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    import os
    import subprocess
    proc=raw_input("Enter the mode :")
    if proc == "start":
      os.getcwd()
      os.chdir(r"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin")
      os.getcwd()
      subprocess.call('catalina.sh jpda start',shell=True)
      print "Tomcat started successfully"
    elif proc == "stop":
      os.getcwd()
      os.chdir(r"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin")
      os.getcwd()
      #subprocess.call('catalina.sh stop',shell=True)
      os.system('catalina.sh stop')
      print "Tomcat stopped successfully"
    elif proc == "restart":
      os.getcwd()
      os.chdir(r"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin")
      os.getcwd()
      subprocess.call('catalina.sh stop',shell=True)
      subprocess.call('catalina.sh start',shell=True)
      print "tomcat restarted successfully"
    else:
     print "error: give any mode"
    print "Thank you"
```

problem is

> subprocess.call('catalina.sh jpda start',shell=True)

not working properly how can i fix this issue and is there are any other why to fix this problem

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so could you add it to the question, please? Thanks!

Comment: it did give me any error but i give me Cygwin Terminal and close it within a few seconds.

Comment: If you run your program from a terminal, it should stay open and let you read the error message

Comment: no Terminal not stay and display error..